# Use Credentials in Constructor without passing them in

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Form that asks the user to type in their username and password.

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public bool LoginStatus { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get { return username.Text; } }

    public string PassWord { get { return password.Text; } }
```

I want to pass in the `UserName` and `PassWord` into the constructor of another class.

```
public ICredentials Creds { get; set; } // <-- Can I use this ??
private readonly ICredentials _credentials;    

public Tools()
{
    _credentials = Creds;
}
```

The `Tools()` class is used frequently and I would like to take the `UserName` and `PassWord` and have them in the constructor without passing them in because then I would have to make changes to all of the instances of the `Tools()` class. Is that possible? Or do I have to pass in the `UserName` and `PassWord` to the constructor?

Comment: `Creds` will *never* be set at the time your constructor invokes.  If you want to centralize this sort of logic, a DI container would be your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to have to supply values to construct an object, then they should not be part of the constructor. A dependency injection container may be able to supply the values with a bit of work to create a dynamic extension, but the reality is (based on your description) that you need to create a parameterless constructor or heavily refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DavidHaney a DI injection system would solve your problem, although it'll require some refactoring.

Another way would be to create a global variable, store the credentials in there and then access this global variable from the Tools class.  Please note that global variables are 'code smell' but sometimes needed.

You can make use of Thread storage, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or you can declare a static variable inside your app.